# How to find the first empty cell in a column, enter a value, and copy that value down to the last row in a table?

Tags: excel, vba

Ultimately, I'm having a hard time piecing together the code I've researched into something that works.

I am trying to enter "1PAE" into the first empty cell in a column. Then copy the value down the rest of the column.  I'm using Column A to identify the last row in the table.

I believe the 2nd example code shown below is the closest I've gotten to something that works.  I've tried to use different versions of the standard FillDown approach.

The 1st example is a version of the code from Scott Holtzman

[Copy and Paste Row and Columns(with formulas) and Paste down to the last row in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36015106/copy-and-paste-row-and-columnswith-formulas-and-paste-down-to-the-last-row-in)

I've switched my focus to the code below.  I'm still getting an error.
Run-time error 1004 - Error 1004 Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed on the last line...LastRow.AutoFill(Destination:=.Range(LastRow), Type:=xlFillValues) = "1PAE"

Sub PAECombineBillDetail()

```
Dim Colm As Range
Dim Col1 As Variant, Col2 As Variant, Col3 As Variant, Col4 As Variant, Col5 As Variant, Col6 As Variant
Dim Col7 As Variant, Col8 As Variant, Col9 As Variant, ColA As Variant
Dim OrgFirstBlank As Long
Dim ColLast As Long
Dim pRange As Range
Dim lRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Range
Dim LegBill As Worksheet
Dim BIL019 As Worksheet
Dim INVHIST As Worksheet

'~~> Set Worksheet Names

Set INVHIST = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CombinedINVHistory")
Set LegBill = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BillingInvHistory")
Set BIL019 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BIL-019")

INVHIST.Select
Set LastRow = Range("B5").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)

    With INVHIST

        '~~> Find Last Row in Col B
        lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> FillDown Formula Lvl3 Acct Name
        .Range("O6:O" & lRow).Formula _
            = "=IF(RC[-3]=""Labor"",INDEX(LBR_CPP5_AcctMap!C1:C15,MATCH(RC[1],LBR_CPP5_AcctMap!C7,0),6),INDEX(NonLBR_CPP5_AcctMap!C1:C12,MATCH(RC[1],NonLBR_CPP5_AcctMap!C7,0),5))"

        '~~> FillDown Formula Lvl3 Acct ID
        .Range("N6:N" & lRow).Formula _
        = "=IF(RC[-2]=""Labor"",INDEX(LBR_CPP5_AcctMap!C1:C15,MATCH(RC[2],LBR_CPP5_AcctMap!C7,0),5),INDEX(NonLBR_CPP5_AcctMap!C1:C12,MATCH(RC[2],NonLBR_CPP5_AcctMap!C7,0),4))"

        '~~> FillDown Formula Lvl2 Acct ID
        .Range("M6:M" & lRow).Formula _
        = "=IF(RC[-1]=""Labor"",INDEX(LBR_CPP5_AcctMap!C1:C15,MATCH(RC[3],LBR_CPP5_AcctMap!C7,0),3),INDEX(NonLBR_CPP5_AcctMap!C1:C12,MATCH(RC[3],NonLBR_CPP5_AcctMap!C7,0),2))"

        '~~> Select LastRow to first blank cell in column B
        LastRow.Select
        '~~> Enter "1PAE" into LastRow and Autofill down the rest of the column.
        LastRow.AutoFill(Destination:=.Range(LastRow), Type:=xlFillValues) = "1PAE"           

    End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

In the end, I need "1PAE" in every cell down the remainder of Column B, while keeping everything above the first blank row untouched.

Comment: `Sheets(Sheet 1)` should probably be `Sheets("Sheet 1")` make sure the very first line in your code is `Option Explicit` then check which warnings you get when you run the code.

Comment: Sorry about that.  There is a lot more code, so I left a lot out.  The sheets all check out.  Here is what it actually looks look like...

Comment: I also have Option Explicit at the top already.  When I run the macro, I get the Run-time error '1004'...Application-defined or object defined error.  When I hit Debug, the code in the first example is highlighted yellow.  .Range(.Cells(ActiveCell, 0), .Cells(ActiveCell, 0)).AutoFill _ Destination:=.Range(.Cells(ActiveCell, 0), .Cells(lRow, 0))

Comment: That is not possible because if you use `Option Explicit` you will get a "Variable is not declared" error at `Set INVHIST = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet 1)`. Because it considers `Sheet 1` to be a variable not a string/text. Please check if you meant `Sheets("Sheet 1")` instead and [edit] your question to correct it to the code you actually use. • Also not that statements starting with a dot `.` like `.Range(…)` only work within a `With` statement.